# limit and integral of continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, continuity

Let $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ be continuous real value function. let $A=\{x\,| \, f(x)=1 \}$.
I prove if A is finite set, $\lim_{n \to \infty} (\int _0 ^1 f(x)^n dx)=0$. if A is countable set, how to prove $\lim_{n \to \infty} (\int _0 ^1 f(x)^n dx)=0$?
or it has counterexample?

Comment: You could try to use that a continous function on a closed interval is uniformly continous to exchange limit and integral.

Comment: how to exchange limit and integral with uniformly continuous? There is f such that f(x)^n is not uniform convergence

Comment: Actually a more general result is true. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3038925/72031 You don't need continuity of $f$. Just its Riemann integrability is needed.

Comment: but i want 0<=f<=1

Comment: You should read the answer in detail and have a look at the theorem at the end. Your set $A$ can be of measure zero and hence uncountable also.

Comment: Your set $A$ is the set of points where integrand does not tend to $0$ and for rest of points the integrand tends to $0$. The proof in my answer shows that if $A$ is of measure zero then the desired limit is $0$. If $A$ is not of measure then the limit will not be zero.