# Uniformly bounded sequence of Riemann integrable functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, riemann-integration, pointwise-convergence

Let {$f_n$} be a uniformly bounded sequence of Riemann int'ble functions on $[a,b]$.If $f_n\rightarrow 0$ pointwise then does it follow that $\int _{[a,b]}f_n\rightarrow0$?

My thoughts: The result doesn't follow from the given assumptions. To justify my claim, I choose $f_n(x)=\frac{x^2}{x^2+(1-nx)^2}$ on $[0,1]$ which satisfies all the criteria. Clearly, $f_n\rightarrow 0$ pointwise but I haven't been able to show that $\int _{[a,b]}f_n$ doesn't converge to $0$ although it's clear that it doesn't.

Are there any other counter-examples to justify this result?. I came up with $f_n(x)=nx(1-x^2)^n$ on $[0,1]$ but this choice of function doesn't have the uniform boundedness. Can anybody provide me with a relatively easy example to go with?

Comment: The intergal does tend to $0$. This is an easy consequence of DCT (Dominated Convergence Theorem) but I don't have a proof without measure theory.

Comment: Then,I guess this result holds since R.I functions on a closed bounded interval is Lebesgue m'ble.

Comment: Yes, RI functions are also Lebesgue integrable and DCT can be applied.

Comment: Too bad I wasn't thinking about that. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Your theorem is equivalent to the theorem of Arzela, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3039030/72031. There is a proof with minimal use of measure theory if the sequence $f_n$ is decreasing. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3038925/72031

Answer (score 5):

Arzela's bounded convergence theorem (1885) states that if $(f_n)$ is a uniformly bounded sequence of Riemann integrable functions on $[a,b]$ that converges pointwise to a Riemann integrable function $f$, then $\int_a^b f_n(x) \, dx \to \int_a^b f(x) \, dx$.

In this case $f = 0$ is Riemann integrable and $\int_a^b f_n(x) \, dx \to 0$ follows.

The assumptions are stronger than in convergence theorems for Lebesgue integrals since the Riemann integrability of the limit function is imposed.  This can be proved without measure theory using **elementary** techniques, for example [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.1439)
.

Comment: +1 Arzela theorem can also be proved as discussed in [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3039030/72031).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Thanks for adding that.

Answer (score 3):

As an immediate consequence of DCT and the fact that RI functions are also Lebesegue integrable (with the same value for the integral) we have $\int_{[a,b]} f_n(x) dx \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can do it in this way, still measure-theoretic: By Egorov, given $\epsilon>0$, some measurable set $S\subseteq [0,1]$ is such that $f_{n}\rightarrow 0$ uniformly on $[0,1]-S$ and $|S|<\epsilon$, then $\left|\displaystyle\int f_{n}\right|=\left|\displaystyle\int_{[0,1]-S}f_{n}+\int_{S}f_{n}\right|\leq\left|\displaystyle\int_{[0,1]-S}f_{n}\right|+\sup_{n}|f_{n}(x)||S|\leq\left|\displaystyle\int_{[0,1]-S}f_{n}\right|+\left(\sup_{n}|f_{n}(x)|\right)\cdot\epsilon$. We know that $\displaystyle\int_{[0,1]-S}f_{n}\rightarrow 0$ by the uniform convergence of $f_{n}\rightarrow 0$ on $[0,1]-S$, so $\left|\displaystyle\int f_{n}\right|$ is arbitrarily small.

Comment: "given $ϵ>0$, some measurable set $S⊆[0,1]$ is such that $f_n→0$ uniformly on $[0,1]−S$ and $|S|<ϵ$"

Is this equivalent to saying that $f_n \rightarrow0$ almost uniformly (which is the end result in Egorov's theorem)?

Comment: We learn Egorov way earlier than DCT, why not this has some virtue? Plus, the domain is finite, and even suites better for Egorov.

Comment: @SL_MathGuy, yes, that is the same saying.

Comment: I learnt Egorovs after DCT. As you  mentioned, the theorem can be applied since the measure space is finite and more importantly, I missed the observation that {$f_n$} is a sequence of measurable functions, which really is the key point here.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, you said that DCT is better known than Egorov, that's just a matter of your taste. Plus, I was using the textbook by J Yeh, and I learned Egorov way earlier than DCT.